# How to convert this to html readable code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have found this on a template and was wondering how do I make this work? I have tried uncommenting it but it doesn't seem to work out.

```
li.dropdown.navbar-cart
                  a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
                      span.icon-basket
                      |
                      span.cart-item-number 2
                  ul.dropdown-menu.cart-list(role='menu')
                      li
                          .navbar-cart-item.clearfix
                              .navbar-cart-img
                                  a(href='#')
                                      img(src='assets/images/shop/product-9.jpg', alt='')
                              .navbar-cart-title
                                  a(href='#') Short striped sweater
                                  |
                                  span.cart-amount 2 &times; $119.00
                                  br
                                  |
                                  strong.cart-amount $238.00
                      li
                          .navbar-cart-item.clearfix
                              .navbar-cart-img
                                  a(href='#')
                                      img(src='assets/images/shop/product-10.jpg', alt='')
                              .navbar-cart-title
                                  a(href='#') Colored jewel rings
                                  |
                                  span.cart-amount 2 &times; $119.00
                                  br
                                  |
                                  strong.cart-amount $238.00
                      li
                          .clearfix
                              .cart-sub-totle
                                  strong Total: $476.00
                      li
                          .clearfix
                              a.btn.btn-block.btn-round.btn-font-w(type='submit') Checkout
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have tried uncommenting it but it doesn't seem to work out."? What is not working?

Comment: @SwatantraKumar Well I manage to uncomment it, but it is not readable in the html file, I still dont know why, like it doesn't create the cart icon and button for the site , it just appears as text :(

Comment: It looks like some sort of HTML Templating language; but I don't know which one - Try searching around for those and find something that formats similar

Comment: It's not the normal html css. Are you using any template engine?

Comment: @SwantraKumar Its Titan Template , not really a template engine as I know [link] https://github.com/technext/Titan/archive/master.zip) you can download the file here and look under index_shop.html and find the html code for the cart which is commented

Comment: @Light Its Titan Template , not really a template engine as I know [link] https://github.com/technext/Titan/archive/master.zip) you can download the file here and look under index_shop.html and find the html code for the cart which is commented

Comment: I have tried writing them an email and their response was ask on stack overflow, you will get help, as it is a free template we do not give any answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, that it's a pug template language, and I just converted it back to html with [pughtml.com:](https://pughtml.com/)

```
<li class="dropdown navbar-cart"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-basket"></span><span class="cart-item-number">2</span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu cart-list" role="menu">
    <li>
        <div class="navbar-cart-item clearfix">
            <div class="navbar-cart-img"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/shop/product-9.jpg" alt=""/></a></div>
            <div class="navbar-cart-title"><a href="#">Short striped sweater</a><span class="cart-amount">2 &times; $119.00</span><br/><strong class="cart-amount">$238.00</strong></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="navbar-cart-item clearfix">
            <div class="navbar-cart-img"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/shop/product-10.jpg" alt=""/></a></div>
            <div class="navbar-cart-title"><a href="#">Colored jewel rings</a><span class="cart-amount">2 &times; $119.00</span><br/><strong class="cart-amount">$238.00</strong></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="cart-sub-totle"><strong>Total: $476.00</strong></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="clearfix"><a class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-font-w" type="submit">Checkout</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```